# Why does not executing the following code cause it to crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I have an app that uses Admob. But since I am supporting versions of iOS 5 and above, I make sure that I don't call Admob code in versions below iOS 6 by doing the following:

```
   if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_5_1) {
        int j = 2;
        j++; //This is just some code so I can use breakpoints for testing.
        NSLog(@"Google Mobile Ads SDK version: %@", [GADRequest sdkVersion]); //Commenting out the line prevents the crash
    }
```

I am testing on iOS 5.1.1. Now if I comment out the NSLog, line, the app works without problem. But if I uncomment it the app crashes almost immediately within the main method:

int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");

I guess its not crashing when it is commented out because the compiler "optimises out" the code since its not used. But then what is the correct way to make sure the code isn't used, and the app doesn't crash ?

EDIT: I edited the code, the if block is not optimised out:

```
        int j = 2;

   if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_5_1) {
        j++; //This is just some code so I can use breakpoints for testing.
        NSLog(@"Google Mobile Ads SDK version: %@", [GADRequest sdkVersion]); //Commenting out the line prevents the crash
    }else{
        j--;
    }

    NSLog(@"%d",j);
```

The output is "1", so the code in the else block executes. So even thought the function call `[GADRequest sdkVersion]` is not made, why does it crash ? Again, if I comment out the function call the app does not crash.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Did you try setting a breakpoint on all Objective-C exceptions in case it's an exception? Does it print any useful info on the console when it crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility that is consistent with what you're describing is that linking to AdMob causes the crash. Sending a message to the `GADRequest` class in your code causes it to link to the `GADRequest` class, whereas if you didn't, it wouldn't link to it.

Why does linking to AdMob cause the crash? Most likely it's because AdMob links to several system frameworks, some of which may not exist on iOS 5 (e.g. `AdSupport` framework), so when it tries to dynamically link to them on app startup, the dynamic linker crashes.

I'm not sure what you can do. Maybe you can try explicitly linking to the system frameworks that AdMob use as "optional" in Xcode? (I haven't tested it.)

Otherwise, you could downgrade to a version of AdMob that supports iOS 5 (according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/rel-notes), any version before 7 should do).

Comment: I did set the frameworks as optional. But it crashes anyway. But do you know if an earlier version of admob will still be supported ?

Answer (score -4):

I dont know why it crashes - but don't support iOS 5. It is pointless. The iOS market split is something like 20% iOS7, 80% iOS8. You cannot buy iOS5 phones, and you cannot install or, or even release apps for it.

Comment: Where does it say that you cannot release apps for it ?

Comment: but I don't think it says that you can't release apps for it.. did I miss something ?

Comment: kinda :) it has to be an iOS8 app, and nobody has iOS5. iOS5 apps do not support 64 bit and the apps have to be 64 bit for the store. Why are you so intent on distributing iOS5?

Comment: I think you're mistaken - you may have to use iOS 8 as your base SDK, but you can still set your deployment target to iOS 5. Secondly, all devices before iOS 5 do not use the 64bit build, they just use the 32bit one. So i Imagine that the 1st generation iPad can do the same. I don't know what you mean by saying it has to be an iOS8 app. There are plenty of people who set a deployment target of iOS7 too.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't answer further. Its less of a real answer and more of a "do you really need to solve this?" discussion.

Comment: @John Please don't mark an answer as correct simply because it is the only answer.  There is a reason that your app is crashing and this response does not address the crash.

Comment: You can have the deployment target for apps as low as iOS 4.3, let alone 5.